# Ansible : [DEPRECATION WARNING]: Using bare variables is deprecated

Tags: ansible

I think this is the part of the playbook that is generating the error. How should I be re-writing this part?

```
roles: 
- role: json-transform
  json_transforms: '{{ clientValidation.json_transforms}}'
```

It throws the following warning:

```
[DEPRECATION WARNING]: Using bare variables is deprecated. Update your playbooks so that the environment value uses the full variable syntax ('{{json_transforms}}'). This feature will be removed in a 
future release. Deprecation warnings can be disabled by setting deprecation_warnings=False in ansible.cfg.
```

Comment: What Ansible version are you using? That syntax looks a little odd to me and normally I'd go with something like: `- { role: json-transform, json_transforms: '{{ clientValidation.json_transforms}}' }` so you might want to try that.

Comment: I am using Ansible 2.0.1
I had already tried what you mentioned and it did not work.

Comment: The syntax doesn't matter- @ydaetskcoR is just using inline dict syntax instead of expanded yaml dict syntax. They're exactly the same thing in the parsed document.

Comment: Seems this question is somehow related to this topic here [1]. Usually happens when you try to validate using then "when" method on a bare variable. From ansible 2.8 and above you should use something like ```when: myVariable|bool``` to be in compliance with the newest standards
[1] https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-role-ntp/issues/59

Answer (score 12):

It doesn't look like there's anything wrong with your top level- it's probably something inside your role. Deprecated bare variables usually occur on a `with_xxx` loop; eg:

```
- hosts: blar
  vars:
    items:
    - one
    - two
  tasks:
  - debug: msg="hi from {{ item }}"
    with_items: items
```

In this case, it's telling you that `with_items: items` should be `with_items: "{{ items }}"`.